# Maintaining a list in a particular order per user, in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of items and set of users. Users can re-order list items. Each user has his own view for the list, he can arrange the items in his own way. One item can be placed in different locations in list for different users. I've to track the item location for users in list item. Please give a suggestion to implement this. The size of the list is not constant. I'm using Java. My intention is I have to show the list for every user in their ordering format. Please Masters give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an ordered list of, well, the order to retrieve items from your master list:

```
List<Foo> items = new ArrayList<Foo>();
// add stuff to items (say, 6 things)

Map<String,List<Integer>> userOrders = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
userOrders.put("A", Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5)); // add user A's order
userOrders.put("B", Arrays.asList(5,4,3,2,1,0)); // add user B's order

// display for userA:
for(Integer i : userOrders.get("A")){
    show(items.get(i)); // show the userA's i-th item
}
```

Here I'm also using a `Map` to hold the orders.  Depending on your application you might use some other scheme to retrieve the user's custom ordering, but the principle will always be the same: if the user can have a custom order, you should store that *ordering* somewhere, and then iterate through the list of things based on that ordering (as shown above).

Also take care with the type of `List` you're using, calling `get` for random access on a `LinkedList` is substantially more costly than on an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Elliot. Can we place the location in item (Foo) itself for every user using anything like Map or any?

Comment: @Jessu: if you want to iterate efficiently through a list of `Foo` I wouldn't count on storing the user preferences on ordering inside of `Foo` -- you can do it, but you'll have to iterate through the entire list at least twice, once to extract the ordering, and a second to order the list; storing order preferences in a separate list allows you to iterate through just once.

Comment: Nice explanation @Mark Elliot, I'll use this. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't they have `class User { String name; List<Foo> items; } `?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do a classic Object Oriented Design for this first, as suggested by glowcoder. Then you will have User class and Item class. User class will have a list of Item instances.

```
class User{
  String userId;
  List<Item> userItems;
}
```

A reverse structure would reflect in the database as well (User Table, Item Table and a User-Item Table with foreign key mappings to the first two tables). The Map of List solution suggested by Mark works, but is not the 'correct' approach in an object oriented language like Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have one location that stores the actual list of items. Then each user gets their own model of the data. It is backed by the actual list, but model is more of a mapping between the actual indexes of each item and the display index the user has for the item. Then you have one viewer that can use the model to display the list in the GUI. As far as the viewer is concerned, the model is telling it the correct indexes. But the model allows for the conversion from displayed order to real order. As the user manipulates the list through the view, you update the index map and never touch the actual data.

Comment: Thanks @unholysampler, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on correct [Answer by rahulmohan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101103/642706), I will add some example code.

Define our `Item` & `User` classes.

```java
record Item( String description ) { }
```

```java
final class User
{
    private final String name;
    private final List < Item > items;

    User ( String name , List < Item > items )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public List < Item > items ( ) { return items; }

    public void addItem ( final Item item )
    {
        this.items.addLast( item );  // Or, before Java 21: `List.add( this.items.size() , item )`.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass( ) != this.getClass( ) ) return false;
        var that = ( User ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.items , that.items );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , items );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "User[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "items=" + items + ']';
    }
}
```

Some example data.

```java
final List < Item > masterListOfItems =
        new ArrayList <>(
                List.of(
                        new Item( "Dog" ) ,
                        new Item( "Cat" ) ,
                        new Item( "Bird" )
                )
        );
final List < User > users =
        new ArrayList <>(
                List.of(
                        new User( "Alice" , new LinkedList <>( masterListOfItems ) ) ,
                        new User( "Bob" , new LinkedList <>( masterListOfItems ) ) ,
                        new User( "Carol" , new LinkedList <>( masterListOfItems ) )
                )
        );
```

Bob prefers cats. So he moves the second item `Cat` into the first position (index zero), above `Dog` item.

```java
// Bob prefers cats.
// Retrieve Bob.
User bob = users.stream( ).filter( user -> user.name( ).equalsIgnoreCase( "Bob" ) ).findAny( ).get( );
System.out.println( "(before move) bob = " + bob );
// Retrieve the Cat item.
Item cat = bob.items( ).stream( ).filter( item -> item.description( ).equalsIgnoreCase( "Cat" ) ).findAny( ).get( );
// To move the position of `Cat` in the list, remove, and add back in.
bob.items( ).remove( cat );
bob.items( ).addFirst( cat );

System.out.println( "(after move) bob = " + bob );
```

When run:

```
(before move) bob = User[name=Bob, items=[Item[description=Dog], Item[description=Cat], Item[description=Bird]]]
(after move) bob = User[name=Bob, items=[Item[description=Cat], Item[description=Dog], Item[description=Bird]]]
```

You said:

> The size of the list is not constant.

I assume that means you want to add an item, and possibly remove. Let's look at addition. We need to add the new item to the master list, and then add the item to each `User` object’s own `List`.

```java
// New item.
Item hamster = new Item( "Hamster" );
// Add new item to the master list.
masterListOfItems.addLast( hamster );
// Add new item to the list contained within each `User` object.
users.forEach( user -> user.addItem( hamster ) );
System.out.println( "(after add) bob = " + bob );
System.out.println( "masterListOfItems = " + masterListOfItems );
```

When run, we see that Bob has his own list ordered by his personal preference while the order of our master list remains undisturbed.

```
(after add) bob = User[name=Bob, items=[Item[description=Cat], Item[description=Dog], Item[description=Bird], Item[description=Hamster]]]
masterListOfItems = [Item[description=Dog], Item[description=Cat], Item[description=Bird], Item[description=Hamster]]
```

Be aware that this use of multiple lists is efficient with memory. The content objects (`User` & `Item` objects) are *not* being duplicated. There is only **one instance of every `Item`** object in memory. Each single instance is shared, by way of a reference, amongst the many `List` objects each owned by a `User` object.